# What is the max number of parameters that can be passed in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Server in qustion is SQL Server 2008.

On the same note, I need to know what is the max length of the string parameter passed in SP?

Comment: please, don't do anything that will require the next coder (that works on this project) to ask questions on SO about fixing a procedure with 2100 parameters!

Comment: It is datawarehouse app. that builds sql on the fly, and nobody ever looks at the parameters. It is all based on metadata it works quite well. Thanks for your concern, I would never use sp to begin with for normal business app.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> What is the max number of parameters
>   that can be passed in stored procedure?

A: [2100](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) - link shamelessly stolen from Andrew's answer.

> On the same note, I need to know what
>   is the max length of the string
>   parameter passes in SP?

You can use VARCHAR(MAX)/NVARCHAR(MAX) datatype, it can store up to 2 GB of data.

Comment: What about dynamic SQL through ADO.NET. Is it same?

Comment: I guess that would be the case, not sure tho.

Comment: @EdgarSalazar source ?

Comment: @Sak exception message said this to me

Answer (score 29):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx), SQL Server limits the number of parameters per stored procedure to 2,100.